# Angular js - ng-class="" with simple condition won't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, view, ng-class

Hi, i'm trying to add a class to an element via `ng-class`.  As you can see, the code is very simple but it doesn't add the class:

```
app.run(function($rootScope, $location,$http,ngDialog,array_helper){
    var update =  function() {
        /*CONFIG PARAMS*/
        $rootScope.config = {};
        $rootScope.config.app_routes = [
            "/",
            "/channels",
            "/channels/create",
            "/users",
            "/auth/login",
            "/auth/signup"
        ];
        console.log($rootScope.config.app_url);
        console.log($rootScope.config.app_routes.indexOf($rootScope.config.app_url));
    };
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function() { 
        update(); 
    });
});
```

Then in the view, i do:

```
<div ng-view ng-animate class="" ng-class="{'slide': config.app_routes.indexOf(config.app_url) == -1}"></div>
```

But it seems it never works, as it never adds the class `slide`.  Meanwhile `console.log` works great and returns -1 only when it is right :O

Comment: As I know, indexOf is not supported in some browsers. If that's the case, you need a polyfill

Comment: @KhanhTO it won't work only where it is supported man :d on Chrome it doesn't works

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your logic into a scope variable:

`<div ng-view ng-animate ng-class="{ 'slide': someVar }"></div>`

and set `$scope.someVar = true` whenever `config.app_routes.indexOf(config.app_url) == -1`. How you do this depends how and when `config.app_routes` is updated.

Comment: I had the same issue using a variable inside controller's vm. Moving the variable to $scope solved the problem.